# Upload an image in wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to upload an image in my plugin. How can i upload this. Can i use move_uploaded_file in wordpress or wordpress have any inbuild method to upload image. Please help me.

Comment: Is it a frontend or backend feature you are looking for? Could something like this help you? http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/

Comment: Its backend feature

Comment: I want to upload image using input type="file" of html.

Comment: Did you try the link in my first comment? Would that work?

Comment: no its not working.

Comment: In move_upload_file use templatepath to save the image.
move_uploaded_file($FILES['file']['tmp_name'],TEMPLATEPATH .'/images/'. $FILES['file'.$i]['name'])